# Where does the shark send the divers?

Tags: untagged

When the Shark moves and displaces divers, do they go to the beach or back to the player's supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the "**Activating the Shark**" rules card:

> any diver in [the spot the shark moves to] and in either spot next to that spot flees off board back to its owner

Meaning the diver is returned to the players supply.